# Returning The Appropriate Concrete Type For Abstract Generic Type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap

I'm having a hard time with StructureMap configuration. I have a ValidationProvider that accepts a Func as its validation factory. I need to supply that using structure map so it would know what implementation of Validator (abstract) it should return. I guess you're already confused so here's some code to clear things out:

```
public class ValidationProvider : IValidationProvider
{
    private readonly Func<Type, IValidator> _validatorFactory;

    public ValidationProvider(Func<Type, IValidator> validatorFactory)
    {
        _validatorFactory = validatorFactory;
    }
```

As you can see, the validation provider delegates the functionality of figuring out what implementation of IValidator is required to the validatorFactory. I also have Validator which implements IValidator.

```
public abstract class Validator<T> : IValidator
{
    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidator.Validate(object entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

        return this.Validate((T)entity);
    }

    protected abstract IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(T entity);
}
```

Then I have a Validator instance for each entity that requires validation, example:

```
public sealed class BidValidator : Validator<Bid>
{
    protected override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(Bid bid)
    {
        if (bid.User.HasEnoughCredits(bid.Item.Category.ListingPrice) == false)
            yield return new ValidationResult("InsufficientCredits", "Not enough credits.");
        if(bid.Item.IsValidBidAmount(bid.Amount) == false)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Amount", "Bid amount has to be higher than last posted bid.");
        if(bid.User.OwnsItem(bid.Item.Id))
            yield return new ValidationResult("InvalidBidder", "User cannot bid on his/her own items.");
    }
}
```

And I've got a NullValidator which is supposed to be the default when there is no implementation of the abstract Validator

```
public sealed class NullValidator<T> : Validator<T>
{
    protected override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(T entity)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<ValidationResult>();  
    }
}
```

So now in StructureMap I need to tie things up together, but I cannot get it to work... Here's what I got:

```
            x.For(typeof(Validator<>)).Use(typeof(NullValidator<>));
            x.For<Validator<Bid>>().Use<BidValidator>();
            x.For<Validator<Rating>>().Use<RatingValidator>();
            x.For<Validator<TopLevelCategory>>().Use<TopLevelCategoryValidator>();
        });

        Func<Type, IValidator> validatorFactory = type =>
        {
            var valType = typeof(Validator<>).MakeGenericType(type.GetType());
            return (IValidator) ObjectFactory.GetInstance(valType);
        };

        container.Configure(x => x.For<IValidationProvider>().Use(() => new ValidationProvider(validatorFactory)));
```

But the line that says `return (IValidator) ObjectFactory.GetInstance(valType);` keeps throwing this exception:

> StructureMap Exception Code:  202 No
>   Default Instance defined for
>   PluginFamily
>   Sharwe.Services.Validation.Validator`1[[System.RuntimeType,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]],
>   Sharwe.Services, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Any way I could get this hooked up?

P.S: if there's an easier way to do this, I'll be glad to know about it. This was not implemented by me, I just liked it and thought is worth giving a shot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is mixed usage of ObjectFactory and the Container object you created...

ObjectFactory creates and manages a container instance, so if you create another container they will have different configuration.

If you use only your container object or only ObjectFactory it should work.

Comment: I think that actually resolved the problem! Thanks a lot man! But, now I am still stuck on ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720605/id-being-rendered-as-null-in-a-typed-razor-view ) so I cannot fully test it and check if the problem was totally resolved. But at least no exception is thrown by that line anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Change the following code:

```
Func<Type, IValidator> validatorFactory = type =>
{
    var valType = typeof(Validator<>).MakeGenericType(type.GetType());
    return (IValidator) ObjectFactory.GetInstance(valType);
};
```

To:

```
Func<Type, IValidator> validatorFactory = type =>
{
    var valType = typeof(Validator<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    return (IValidator) ObjectFactory.GetInstance(valType);
};
```

You are supplying a `Type` argument and calling `type.GetType()` which will return type `Type` instance of that `Type`... uhhmm.. still following me? The exception message actually says it all:

> No Default Instance defined for
>   Validator<System.RuntimeType>

Comment: @Steven: Eventhough that made it pickup the right type, I still got almost the same error, except now it's telling me there's no default instance defined for this specific type. Check this out, might be helpful: http://i55.tinypic.com/343mewz.jpg

Comment: @Steven: I think I actually understand the error better now, I need to find a way to build an instance of BidValidator for Validator<Bid>...

Comment: @Kassem: I'm not sure why you got this error, since you've seemed to register the `Validator<Bid>` using this line: `x.For<Validator<Bid>>().Use<BidValidator>();`

Comment: @Steven: Exactly... this is really weird... I hope someone on the StructureMap team would see this question and tell us what's wrong... It doesn't make sense!

Comment: @Kassem: Have you tried minimizing the scope to find the problem? What does the following do: `var c = new Container(); c.Configure(r => r.For<Validator<Bid>>().Use<BidValidator>()); c.GetInstance<Validator<Bid>>();` ?

Comment: @Steven: Just like Robin Clowers said, it is because I was using ObjectFactory.GetInstance(). I replaced it with container.GetInstance() and that resolved the issue. But now I'm stuck on this weird issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720605/id-being-rendered-as-null-in-a-typed-razor-view . Thanks for you help :)